# Creating a new variable based on prior history

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, tidyr

I have data where I need to create a variable based on prior history, for example

```
 created<- c(2009,2010,2010,2011, 2012, 2011)
 person <- c(A, A, A, A, B, B)
 location<- c('London','Geneva', 'London', 'New York', 'London', 'London')
 df <- data.frame (created, person, location)
```

I want to create a variable called 'existing' that takes into account the prior years and sees if he/she has lived in that place and gives a value of 0 if the place is old(and they lived there. Any suggestions?

```
 library(dplyr) 
 df %>% group_by(person) %>% mutate (existing=0)

  existing<- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0,1)
```

Comment: why is the value of the 5th row is 1, instead of 0? (same for the last row)

Comment: You are right it is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(person, location) %>%
 mutate(existing = +(1:n() == 1))

  created person location existing
    <dbl> <fct>  <fct>       <int>
1    2009 A      London          1
2    2010 A      Geneva          1
3    2010 A      London          0
4    2011 A      New York        1
5    2012 B      London          1
6    2011 B      London          0
```

If sorting is required:

```
df %>%
 group_by(person, location) %>%
 arrange(created, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
 mutate(existing = +(1:n() == 1))
```

Comment: Can we sort by year created as 2012 ahead of 2011?

Comment: Do you mean sorting it in a descending order?

Comment: yeah ascending i guess it is in the right order for A 2009-2011 and it should be 2011 and 2012 for B in that order, thanks

Comment: Sure, you can do `df %>%
 group_by(person, location) %>%
 arrange(created, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
 mutate(existing = +(1:n() == 1))` :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated information from OP, we need to first `arrange` the data by `person` and year (`created`) and then use `duplicated`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   arrange(person, created) %>% 
   group_by(person) %>% 
   mutate(existing = +(!duplicated(location)))

#  created person location existing
#    <dbl> <fct>  <fct>       <int>
#1    2009 A      London          1
#2    2010 A      Geneva          1
#3    2010 A      London          0
#4    2011 A      New York        1
#5    2011 B      London          1
#6    2012 B      London          0
```

Comment: could you explain what does the `+` do ?

Comment: @Metariat `duplicated` returns logical values. `+` ahead converts the logical values to integer values. So `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` to 0. Check `+TRUE` and `+FALSE`.

Comment: I think that you need to take into account the year in your solution

Comment: @Metariat I too initially thought the same but OP's expected output doesn't reflect that. In the expected output for group `A` 0 is given to 2010 and not 2009 for `London` but for group `B` 0 is given to 2011 and not 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
with(df, ave(location, person, FUN = function(i)as.integer(!duplicated(i))))
#[1] "1" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

another option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[order(person, created), existing := c(1L, rep(0L, .N-1L)), .(person, location)]
```

output:

```
   created person location existing
1:    2009      A   London        1
2:    2010      A   Geneva        1
3:    2010      A   London        0
4:    2011      A New York        1
5:    2012      B   London        0
6:    2011      B   London        1
```